# Get facebook page posts ordered by "post reach" using graph explorer / fql

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the top 5 posts sorted by post reach (not post impression). What I have done so far:

I am querying something like `{page-id}/feed/?order={need_something_to_sort_with}&limit=5&until=1402549200&since=1399957200&suppress_http_code=1&period=lifetime`. That fetches the last 5 posts in the timeline. I have also tried fetching all the posts within a timeline and fetching insights for each one and sorting by the fetched insights, but that's way slower than what I need.

I even tried using FQL, for example like this:

```
SELECT 
message, created_time, likes.count, share_count , comment_info.comment_count, impressions  
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = {page-id} AND created_time  >  1  
ORDER BY  impressions   DESC LIMIT 5
```

but firstly,  I have no way to order by post_reach and secondly, facebook is discouraging the use of FQL as it will be deprecated after v2.0 api.

What is the least time consuming way to do it ( and preferably with the lowest amount of api calls)?

Comment: There's nothing like a `post_reach` field, and there's no `order` parameter as well with the Graph API.

Comment: @Tobi post_reach is just an example that I tried. I would need the posts to be sorted according to their reach ( not impression, check the comparison https://www.facebook.com/help/274400362581037).

Comment: @tobi, is there a way using fql may be? Does this mean that graph api is not able to return sorted data?

Comment: No, you cannot specify an ordering by a specific field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#reading

Comment: You might want to look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights#post_impressions